# Can a REST API be used within a Web API service?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I need to create a Web API "wrapper" that is consumed by a client, but in this Web API Service, I actually need to create a POST request to a different REST API service that is running on the same IIS server that does some work and returns StringContent that I pass back to the client via a JSON HttpResponse.  Is this possible? Instead of the client making direct calls to the actual REST API and returning data they don't need/want, they would call my Web API service and I would only return them the required data.  I know this was done in the old SOAP WSDL model.

If I need the client to pass in a couple parameters that are required for my POST request, would I be having the client use a GET or POST request?

Comment: Yes, you can wrap the API. However, if they are both on the same IIS server, then why can't you share the same code module without the network overhead to pass the messages?

Comment: That is a rather broad question. Do you want to access all endpoints of the actual API service or only a limited number of the endpoints? In other words, do you want to create a proxy service or a limited/custom API for the client, where the "backstage"-API has many more endpoints? Both alternatives can be implemented but will need different approaches. As to the other question: Whether you should use GET or POST largely depends on what kind of operation you have in mind. The number and size of parameters for a GET-request may sometimes be a limiting factor.

Comment: Sure that’s possible. Usually a POST action means a change of some state in that case hiding that behind a GET isn’t advisable

Answer (score 1):

This is an sample code i used call API inside another API using POST method.

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
                        string query;
                        using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>()
                        {
                            {"username", username},
                            {"password", password}
                        }))
                        {
                            query = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        }

                        var model = new{
                            username = txtUsername.Text,
                            password = txtPassword.Text
                        };
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
                        var user = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                        using (var response = await client.PostAsync(@"http://localhost/dataagent/api/user/authenticate", user))
                        {
                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                // handle result here

                            }
                        }
}
```